# Can't understand rust lifetime conflict

Tags: rust, lifetime

I was doing a dummy app to get a grasp on Rust concepts.
While doing an XML structure I got the error

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in
> function call due to conflicting requirements

The definition is

```rust
impl<'a> XmlFile<'a>
```

and

```rust
pub fn get_node<'b>(self, node: &'b [u8]) -> &'b [u8]
```

From what I understand, the Rust compiler does not like that the return variable can be dropped after the function ends, if the XML file drops at a different time (since they have `'a` and `'b` lifetimes).
But if I put the same, I get the error

> lifetime 'a is already in scope

, so I don't see a way to solve the error.

Any idea what I am missing? I think I must still be lacking some Rust concept.

Edit: Misconception from my part adding the code that causes the problem

```rust
#[allow(unused_parens)] 
pub struct  XmlFile<'a> {
    last_open_node: &'a[u8],
    last_published: String,
    index_pos: u64,
    content: &'a[u8],
}

impl<'a> XmlFile<'a> {

    pub fn new<'b: 'a>(file: &'b [u8]) -> XmlFile<'b> {
        let new_xml = XmlFile {
        last_open_node: &[0: u8],
        last_published: "".to_string(),
        index_pos: 0,
        content: file,
        };
        return new_xml;
    }
    pub fn get_node<'b: 'a>(&self, node: &'b [u8]) -> &'b [u8] {
        let buf_index: u64 = 0;
        let has_matched: bool = false;
        self.index_pos = 0;

        for c in self.content {
            self.index_pos += 1;
            if (c == &b'<') {
                buf_index = self.index_pos;
                while (c != &b' ') {
                    for b in node {
                        if b == &self.content[buf_index as usize] {
                            has_matched = true;
                            buf_index += 1
                        } else {
                            has_matched = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if has_matched {
                        while(self.content[buf_index as usize] != b'>'){
                            buf_index+=1;
                        }
                         let r  =  &self.content[self.index_pos as usize..buf_index as usize];
                         return r;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return &[0 : u8];
    }

pub fn get_rss_version<'b:'a>(&self) -> Result<u64 , &'static str>{
        let found_slice = Self::get_node(&self, "rss".as_bytes());
        if(found_slice != &[0:u8]){
            let version_value = Self::get_value(found_slice);
            if(version_value.is_ok()){
                return Ok(version_value.unwrap()) ;

            }
            else{
                return Err("Couldn't retrieve version from tag");
            }
        }
        else{
            println!("Couldn't find tag <rss");
            return Err("Couldn't find tag <rss");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use this? Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit it into your question.

Comment: This error doesn't come from the definitions alone, it comes from uses that conflicts with those definitions. Please include the code that causes the error.

Comment: Note that `get_node()` takes ownership of `self`, which is probably not want you want if this method is a "getter" because the `XmlFile` will get dropped when `get_node()` returns. You probably mean `&self`, but as the other comments say, details are required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your signature for `get_node`:

```rust
pub fn get_node<'b: 'a>(&mut self, node: &'b [u8]) -> &'b [u8] { ... }
```

and what you're actually returning within this method:

```rust
let r = &self.content[self.index_pos as usize..buf_index as usize];
return r;
```

The signature for `get_node` indicates this method will be returning a sub-slice of `node`, but you're actually returning a sub-slice of the `XmlFile`'s `content`.

One solution to the problem is to understand that the return value isn't a part of `node`, but instead a part of `self.content`. Therefore, we can change the signature to:

```rust
pub fn get_node<'b>(&mut self, node: &'b [u8]) -> &'a [u8] { ... }
```

In this case we can even elide the manual specification of lifetimes entirely:

```rust
pub fn get_node(&mut self, node: &[u8]) -> &[u8] { ... }
```

Here's a cleaned up version of your `get_node` method that actually compiles:

```rust
pub fn get_node(&mut self, node: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
    let mut buf_index: u64;
    let mut has_matched: bool = false;
    self.index_pos = 0;

    for c in self.content {
        self.index_pos += 1;
        if c == &b'<' {
            buf_index = self.index_pos;
            while c != &b' ' {
                for b in node {
                    if b == &self.content[buf_index as usize] {
                        has_matched = true;
                        buf_index += 1
                    } else {
                        has_matched = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if has_matched {
                    while self.content[buf_index as usize] != b'>' {
                        buf_index += 1;
                    }
                    let r = &self.content[self.index_pos as usize..buf_index as usize];
                    return r;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return &[0u8];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @flumpb , still have trouble to understand why it asked a lifetime, but your solution works.